# What a common abbreviation for two's complement code

Tags: abbreviations, computing

What a common abbreviation for *two's complement code*? I've searched on Google, and find *"TCC"* as a required abbreviation on [thefreedictionary](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/Two%27s+Complement+Code). Is it commonly recognized? Or may be there are some other suggestions?

Comment: See also: http://www.acronymfinder.com/Two%27s-Complement-Code-%28TCC%29.html However, while *TC* is indeed used for *two's compliment*, TCC is rarely used in this sense.

Comment: Good question. I don't know one. Maybe invent your own. Subscript 2'?

Comment: Can someone please invent one?  I've come to this question to see if there is one, and found that I had already upvoted it at some point in the past

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "Naming" is specified as off topic in [the help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be one.

I have a Master's degree in CS and about 25 years in the industry under my belt, and have never heard of one. Of course that isn't authoritative, so I checked out the Wikipedia pages for [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) and for [Method of Complements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_complements). No abbreviation was found in there. There's a fair bit of math going on in those pages to explain the concept. IMHO, if the mathematicians didn't bother with a notation for it, then there probably isn't much of one.

In fact, it looks like "Two's Complement" itself is a bit of an abbreviation. For completeness sake you really have to specify how many bits you are working with, as well as whether you are talking about the [number format, or the operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Potential_ambiguities_of_terminology) itself.

Comment: With similar (though not quite as much) background, my experience is the same.

Answer (score 1):

We used to the term a lot when talking about computer samples (this was 20 years ago), in casual speech we would say "two's comp".

We also had a short hand (we would need a button and "two's comp" is a bit long) but I can not remember right now. Something like 2n-1 but I am really not sure now but it was represented in other software like this too...

Answer (score 1):

I'm unclear on whether "signed two's complement" and "two's complement" are identical concepts, but they do have abbreviations appearing in more than one place:

[ECE230 Review](https://www.egr.msu.edu/classes/ece331/mason/web_files/N0_230review.pdf) by Andrew Mason, Michigan State University says:

> Express numbers in signed 2 s complement (**S2C**) form, perform
> 2’s complement operation, and evaluate subtraction using S2C.

and

> 2’s Complement = **2C**

He likewise uses it in [these notes](https://mediaspace.msu.edu/media/ECE331_M1B.1.0-18min/1_84rdtzsk):

> And, we will move on to the one that is important, signed two's complement form. So, I'm going to abbreviate this throughout the notes as **S2C**: signed two's complement.

[CMSC 311 Computer Organization: Jolly Numbers Notes or Representing Numbers in the Computer](http://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Emeesh/cmsc411/local-links/numbers/node5.html) by Nikos Drakos & Ross Moore says:

> Signed 2's complement (or sign 2's complement) (**s2c**) is a modification of the sign-magnitude form in which addition and subtraction work the way that you expect them to.